# ¿Cómo puedo coger la primera letra de cada palabra en una cadena?

Tags: python

¿Cómo se pude tomar de una cadena de tipo string en python los primeros dígitos?

Ejemplo:

Entrada -> `hola mundo python`

Salida -> `hmp`

(la primera letra de la cadena h ya sé sacarla, pero no la m y la p).

Intenté con un método split pero no me funcionó:

```
elif (com=="paterno"):
            com2 = raw_input("Entrada: ")

            letra2 = com2[0]
            tabla()
        elif (com=="libro"):
            com2 = raw_input("Entrada: ")
            print com2.splitlines() 
            tabla()
```

Comment: Deberias de poner el codigo de lo que has intentado.

Comment: ¿`a = "".join(list(x[0] for x in 'hola mundo python'.split(' ')))`?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
string = 'hola mundo python'
words = string.split(' ') 
character = ''

for word in words:
   character += word[0]

print(character)
#Out:
     'hmp'
```

El Metodo `string.split(' ')` lo que hace es romper la cadena de texto en este caso `'hola mundo python'` donde encuentre caracteres iguales a `' '` y retorna una lista de varias string, por ejemplo:

tenemos el siguiente string

`string = 'hola mundo python'` y ejecutamos el metodo .split(), `string.split(' ')` este metodo retorna la siguiente lista

`['hola', 'mundo', 'python']`

y en el bucle recorre la lista y concatena la primera letra de casa una de las palabras

Comment: Buenas @Luis, te recomiendo que te pases por el [tour] y por [answer] para que conozcas el funcionamiento básico del sitio! Tu respuesta es buena, pero podría ser mejor si agregas alguna explicación sobre lo que hace tu código, así ayudaras a que los demás entiendan tu solución :)

Comment: Agrega por favor una explicación de lo que realiza el código, es importante.

Answer (score 1):

Si has intentado usando `split()` vas por un buen camino. Lo que tienes que tener en cuenta es que `split()` "desarma" tu cadena y la convierte en una `Lista` de palabras, usando el espacio como separador de palabras (eventualmente se podría se podría separara por otro caracter).

```
cadena = "hola mundo python"
palabras = cadena.split()
print(palabras)
['hola', 'mundo', 'python']
```

Teniendo una lista de palabras, lo que nos faltaría hacer es recorrer esta lista y "extraer" el primer caracter de cada una, para hacer esto último, podemos usar un "slice" mediante los corchetes y un índice, ej: `"Hola"[0] > "H"` y para recorrer la lista usamos un ciclo:

```
palabras = cadena.split()
nueva_cadena = ""
for p in palabras:
    nueva_cadena = nueva_cadena + p[0]

print(nueva_cadena)

'hmp'
```

Como verás, además cada caracter se va concatenando al siguiente en una nueva variable `nueva_cadena`.

Por último no puedo dejar de comentarte que todo el código anterior se podría escribir de una forma más "Pythonica" es decir más simple, usando una técnica llamada comprensión de listas:

```
nueva_cadena = "".join([palabra[0] for palabra in cadena.split()])
```

Aquí simplemente armamos una nueva lista con el primer caracter de cada palabra: `[palabra[0] for palabra in cadena.split()]` y para terminar usamos el método `join()` de los strings, que justamente concatenan una lista en una cadena final.

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvió mucho